# Вывести цикл с определеного числа

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```
<template>
  <div>
    <p v-for="n in 21">{{ n }}</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

  export default {
    data() {
        return {
            n: 8,
        }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Подскажите мне надо вывести цикл начиная с 8 и заканчивая 21, а у меня выводит начиная с 1

Comment: самый простой вариант 
data(){ 
return { numbers: new Array(21 - 8).fill(1).map((_, idx) => idx + 8) } 
}
А в шаблоне v-for="n in numbers"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не очень хорошая практика использовать v-for и v-if, но если задача чисто теоретическая, то подходит.

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    n: 8,
  },
  template: `  <div>
    <p v-for="(curr, index) in 21" v-if="index + 1 >= n">{{ curr }}</p>
  </div>`,
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
</div>
```

Лучше всего использовать computed property, для подобных задач.

```js
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    n: 8,
    all: 21,
  },
  template: `<div>
    <p v-for="curr in rows">{{ curr }}</p>
  </div>`,
  computed: {
    rows() {
      return new Array(this.all + 1 - this.n).fill(1).map((_, index) => index + 8)
    }
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: А если не чисто теоретическая ?)))